# React redux TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having an issue with my show page after I implemented redux everything.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/containers/MovieShowContainer.js:72
  69 |  let loadingState = state.reviews.moviesLoaded[movieId] || "notSarted"
  70 |  return {
  71 |   movies: state.movies.movieList.find(movie => movie.id == movieId),
> 72 |   reviews: state.reviews.reviewList.filter(review =>  review.movie.id == movieId),
     | ^  73 |   loadingState
  74 |  };
  75 | 
View compiled
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
src/containers/MovieShowContainer.js:72
  69 |  let loadingState = state.reviews.moviesLoaded[movieId] || "notSarted"
  70 |  return {
  71 |   movies: state.movies.movieList.find(movie => movie.id == movieId),
> 72 |   reviews: state.reviews.reviewList.filter(review =>  review.movie.id == movieId),
     | ^  73 |   loadingState
  74 |  };
  75 | 
View compiled
▶ 15 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/actions/movies.js:38
  35 | fetch(`http://localhost:3001/movies/${movieId}`)
  36 | .then (res => res.json())
  37 | .then((movieReviewsJson) => {
> 38 |    dispatch({type: SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS,
     | ^  39 |     payload: movieReviewsJson,
  40 | })
  41 | });
```

the above is the actual error. and coming next is my code.

action/movies.js

```
import { 
    START_LOADING_MOVIES,
    SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIES,
    START_LOADING_MOVIE,
    SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS
    
} from './index'


export  const fetchMovies = () =>{
    return(dispatch) =>{
        dispatch({type: START_LOADING_MOVIES})
         fetch('http://localhost:3001/movies', { 
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
     })

       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(moviesJson => {
        dispatch({type: SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIES,
            payload: moviesJson
        
        })
       });
    }
}

export  const fetchMoviesById = (movieId) =>{
    return(dispatch) =>{
        dispatch({type: START_LOADING_MOVIE, payload: movieId})

        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/movies/${movieId}`)
        .then (res => res.json())
        .then((movieReviewsJson) => {
           dispatch({type: SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS,
            payload: movieReviewsJson,
        })
        });
    }
}
```

reducers/movies.js

```
import { 
  // ADD_MOVIE,
  START_LOADING_MOVIES,
  SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIES,
  SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS,
  // FAILED_LOADING_MOVIES
  
  
} from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    LoadingState: "notStarted",
    movieList: []
}

export default function MoviesReducer(state = initialState, 
    action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case START_LOADING_MOVIES:

       return {...state, LoadingState: 'inProgress'}
      
      case SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIES:

        return {
          movieList: action.payload, 
          LoadingState: 'Successfull'
        };

      case SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS:
        const foundMovie = state.movieList.find(movie => movie.id === action.payload.movie.id)
        if(foundMovie) {
          return { 
            state
          } 
        } else {
          return {
              ...state,
             movieList: state.movieList.concat(action.payload.movie),
            }
        }

      default:

     return state;
   }

}
```

reducers/review.js

```
import { 
    SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS,
    START_LOADING_MOVIE
} from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    moviesLoaded: {},
    reviewList: []
};

export default function reviewsReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {

     case START_LOADING_MOVIE: {
        return {
        ...state,
        moviesLoaded: {...state.moviesLoaded, [action.payload]: "inProgress"}
        }
     }

     case SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS:
         return {
          moviesLoaded: {
            ...state.moviesLoaded, 
            [action.payload.movie.id]: "successfull",
          },
          reviewList: state.reviewList.concat(action.payload.reviews)

         };
        default: 
        return state;
    }
}
```

containers/movieShowContainer.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {fetchMoviesById} from '../actions/movies'



export  class MovieShowContainer extends Component {

    

  componentDidMount(){
    const movieId = this.props.match.params.id
    this.props.DispatchfetchMovies(movieId)
  }
    

    render() {
        if (this.props.loadingState !== "successfull"){
            return <div>Loading content</div>
        }

        return (
            <>
            <section className="max-w-6xl w-11/12 mx-auto mt-16">
                <h1 >Title: {this.props.movie.title}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <h1>Genre: {this.props.movie.genre}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <h1>Classification: {this.props.movie.classification}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <h1>Duration: {this.props.movie.duration}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <h1>Release: {this.props.movie.release_date}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <h1>Director: {this.props.movie.director}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <h1>Description: {this.props.movie.description}</h1>
                <br></br>
               

            </section>
            <button className="inline-block border border-blue-500 rounded py-2 px-3 bg-blue-500 text-white mx-44" type="button"><Link to={`/movies/${this.props.movie.id}/reviews/new`}>CREATE A REVIEW</Link></button>

            
            <div className="max-w-6xl w-11/12 mx-auto mt-16">
              {this.state.reviews.map((review) => {
               return(
                <React.Fragment key={review.id}>
                <h2>rating: {review.rating}</h2>
                <h3>review: {review.comment}</h3>
                <br></br>
                </React.Fragment>
                )
              })
              
              }
             
              </div>
            <button className="inline-block border border-blue-500 rounded py-2 px-3 bg-blue-500 text-white mx-44" type="button"><Link to={`/`}>BACK</Link></button>
          </>
           
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, {match: {params} }) => {
  const movieId = params.id
  let loadingState = state.reviews.moviesLoaded[movieId] || "notSarted"
  return {
   movies: state.movies.movieList.find(movie => movie.id == movieId),
   reviews: state.reviews.reviewList.filter(review =>  review.movie.id == movieId),
   loadingState
  };
 
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
   DispatchfetchMovies: (movieId) => dispatch(fetchMoviesById(movieId))
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
(MovieShowContainer)
```

the show page was working before I added the reducers/review.js and now it says the review is undefined. I appreciate any help with this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing the state as an object on the following case.

```
case SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS:
        const foundMovie = state.movieList.find(movie => movie.id === action.payload.movie.id)
        if(foundMovie) {
          return { 
            state
          } 
        } else {
          return {
              ...state,
             movieList: state.movieList.concat(action.payload.movie),
            }
        }
```

when it was supposed to be like this

```
case SUCCESSFULLY_LOADED_MOVIE_REVIEWS:
        const foundMovie = state.movieList.find(movie => movie.id === action.payload.movie.id)
        if(foundMovie) {
          return state
            
          
        } else {
          return {
              ...state,
             movieList: state.movieList.concat(action.payload.movie),
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though `review.movie` is `undefined` for at least one item in your `state.reviews.reviewList` array.  You'll want to figure out why that is.  Possibly your API data isn't exactly the same format that you think it is.

You can prevent the error by using the [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
reviews: state.reviews.reviewList.filter(review => review?.movie?.id === movieId)
```